# Bumpbox (lightbox alternative) width set to 100% instead of 800pixels

Tags: javascript, lightbox

I'm using this plugin
http://www.artviper.net/website-tools/bumpbox-lightbox.php
to display flash files. I need to change width and height of the window to 100% instead of pixels. I uploaded the script here:
http://www.bodom.eu/bumpbox/bumpbox-2.1.js

I use this link to display flash from my html file:
`<a href="01_ka01.swf" class="bump" rel="800-600"></a>`

When no rel is defined, script use the default value 640x480 from bumpbox-2.1.js (exactly it is `maxw = 640;` and `maxh = 480;` - at line 121).

So, I need to change that rel to percentage value, or that default value in the .js file. I've tried add `width="100%" height="100%"` to that anchor, but it didn't work. I've also tried change `maxw=640;` to `maxw='100%';` but with no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

w = window.getSize().x.toInt();
h = window.getSize().y.toInt();

that means you know the dimensions of the window.

maxw = w;
maxh = h;

should do the trick.

Comment: artViper, you're the developer of bumpbox? It's really awesome script! I tried your tip and it perfectly worked, but I realize, that I cannot see the off button:( Is it possible to set it for example to 90%? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

yes, we're the developers of this script. Glad it works out for you now ;)

Comment: I think that Bumpbox is best of lightbox clones, artViper, really great job! Could you, please, check this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6927350/flash-in-fullscreen-mode-works-in-embed-but-not-work-within-a-tag