# Flash in fullscreen mode works in <embed>, but not work within <a> tag

Tags: javascript, html, flash, lightbox

I have this code

```
<div id="c01" class="hider">
< a href="flash.swf" class="bump">flash</a>
</div>
```

and it displays flash content within a bumpbox (lightbox alternative) window. It works perfectly, but there is a fullscreen button in the flash animation and it do not works. The other button (to stop the animation) works ok.

I find out, that with this

```
<embed src="flash.swf" width="100%" height="100%" allowFullScreen="true"> </embed>
```

fullscreen button works fine, but the flash animation runs since the page is loaded and I have about 50 of those animations, so I need to run only one of them at a time. I need to make it clickable (within ) and with working fullscreen button at the same time. Is it possible? Thank you!

Comment: bumpbox probably doesn't set the `allowfullscreen` attribute. If the flash is being loaded in an iframe, you may be able to add the attribute using JavaScript on a bumpbox event (I don't know if bumpbox triggers any custom events).

Comment: Thank you zzzzBov, I use this event listener, how do I add allowfullscreen attribute?      google.maps.event.addListener(pano02,'click',function(){fireEvent(document.getElementById("c01").getElementsByTagName("a")[0],'click');})

Comment: Can you show the lines where you embed the various bumpbox scripts?

Comment: shanethehat, please check this http://www.bodom.eu/fsproblem

Comment: Answer to this thread is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938083/swf-works-within-embed-only-not-working-with-bumpbox-lightbox-alternative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're having is actually coming from Mootools.  Mootools has an Flash embed class called [Swiff](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Utilities/Swiff), which is what BumpBox uses when you pass an SWF in your link.

Unfortunately, I think you're either going to have to hack into BumpBox or Mootools to get full screen permission working.

If you look into the expanded version of BumpBox 2.0.1, you will see where Swiff is instantiated, around line 372:

```
var obj = new Swiff(content, {
    id: 'video',
    width: maxw-40,
    height: maxh-40,
    container: div
})
```

You may be able to pass in the additional parameter you require here, which would look something like this:

```
var obj = new Swiff(content, {
    id: 'video',
    width: maxw-40,
    height: maxh-40,
    container: div,
    params: {
        allowFullScreen: true
    },
})
```

If that fails you will have to make the adjustment to the Swiff class itself.  Open up Mootools and search for `Swiff=new Class`.  That will lead you to the code that creates the Flash object.  Finding the params list should be easy from there, it looks like:

```
params:{quality:"high",allowScriptAccess:"always",wMode:"window",swLiveConnect:true}
```

and you would just need to add the fullscreen permission:

```
params:{allowFullScreen:true,quality:"high",allowScriptAccess:"always",wMode:"window",swLiveConnect:true}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers can't open a Flash file without Flash container (embed).
The embed code in your post is fine, put it on a PHP page and replace:

```
src="flash.swf"
```

with

```
<?php echo $_GET['flashurl']; ?>
```

Then you can put as link: `nameofphpscript.php?flashurl=flash.swf`

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand. With what I have to replace 'src="flash.swf"'? And don't understand what to do with the php link. I'm not php coder:(