# swf works within <embed> only - not working with bumpbox (lightbox alternative)

Tags: javascript, html, flash, mootools, flowplayer

I have this code http://www.bodom.eu/fsproblem
There is one .swf within  tag and when you click on full screen button, it WORKS.

When you click on flash01 link, there is the same .swf within < a> tag (in lightbox style window), where it does NOT WORK.
All I need is to make work the fullscreen button in the bumpbox window. Thank you very much.

Bumpbox use mootools and flowplayer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flash in fullscreen mode works in <embed>, but not work within <a> tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6927350/flash-in-fullscreen-mode-works-in-embed-but-not-work-within-a-tag)

Comment: Why do you want to embed Flash in a <a> tag?

Comment: You're right, shanethehat, it's similar, but in the last thread answers get wrong direction for me. Here it is simplified as possible and with code example, so hopefully anyone can see what I need to do. Anyway, sorry for duplicity:(

Comment: Laurent, I have about 50 flashes on one web page, so I need to display it after click on something..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're having is actually coming from Mootools.  Mootools has an Flash embed class called [Swiff](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Utilities/Swiff), which is what BumpBox uses when you pass an SWF in your link.

Unfortunately, I think you're either going to have to hack into BumpBox or Mootools to get full screen permission working.

If you look into the expanded version of BumpBox 2.0.1, you will see where Swiff is instantiated, around line 372:

```
var obj = new Swiff(content, {
    id: 'video',
    width: maxw-40,
    height: maxh-40,
    container: div
})
```

You may be able to pass in the additional parameter you require here, which would look something like this:

```
var obj = new Swiff(content, {
    id: 'video',
    width: maxw-40,
    height: maxh-40,
    container: div,
    params: {
        allowFullScreen: true
    },
})
```

If that fails you will have to make the adjustment to the Swiff class itself.  Open up Mootools and search for `Swiff=new Class`.  That will lead you to the code that creates the Flash object.  Finding the params list should be easy from there, it looks like:

```
params:{quality:"high",allowScriptAccess:"always",wMode:"window",swLiveConnect:true}
```

and you would just need to add the fullscreen permission:

```
params:{allowFullScreen:true,quality:"high",allowScriptAccess:"always",wMode:"window",swLiveConnect:true}
```

Comment: Dreamveawer doesn't allow me to use params in Bumpbox js file, but as you say, I added it to mootools and it is working perfectly! Thank you very much.